# I used to not need "-i" when using base64

Tags: macos, base64

I am using macOs 13.6.1 (22G313) for a machine.

I used to be able to `base64` a .p12 file (maybe 1 - 3 years ago) using the following format from the terminal:

```
base64 mastercard-track.p12 > mastercard-track_base64.txt
```

Now when I attempt to use the `base64` program like that, I get this error:

```
base64: invalid argument mastercard-track.p12
Usage:  base64 [-hDd] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -Dd, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)
```

Is the `base64` program I used to use different now?

Comment: Are you certain you did not use to do `base64 < mastercard-track.p12 > mastercard-track_base64.txt`, redirecting both into and out of the utility?

Comment: Yes - certain of that - I think I've figured it out and will post an answer - it appears that the `base64` program has changed - or maybe I used a different one? Not sure.

Answer (score 6):

You used to use `base64` installed from Homebrew (it installs [John Walker's `base64` implementation](https://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64/)).  You no longer have that installed so instead you use Apple's `/usr/bin/base64`.  The `base64` utility shipped with macOS has a different command line semantics (different options etc., it's not a standardised utility), while the `base64` provided by Homebrew (and possibly by other package managers on macOS) is the same that you will find in ports/packages on OpenBSD, FreeBSD, and NetBSD, while Linux usually uses the coreutils implementation.

You may use an input redirection along with your already existing output redirection to make your shell code more portable:

```bash
base64 <mastercard-track.p12 >mastercard-track_base64.txt
```

This has the benefit of working with both the Apple `base64` and the `base64` utility installed from Homebrew. It is also compatible with the coreutils variant of `base64`.

Comment: Great point on Homebrew! I must have been using that originally...

Comment: I tested using `base64 <mastercard-track.p12 >mastercard-track_base64.txt` and it unfortunately doesn't format the txt file correctly. The txt file has to be lines of exactly 64 characters except for the last line. The old Homebrew base64 app formatted it this way by nature but base64 on unix doesn't (hence I have to specify "-b 64" on the unix program)

Comment: @ZackMacomber You could pass it through "fold -w 64", but you do whatever you feel is easiest.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the `base64` program has changed or I somehow used a different one (most likely I used the Homebrew `base64`).

Using the following `unix` command worked successfully for me:

```
base64 -b 64 -i mastercard-track.p12 -o mastercard-track_base64.txt
```